# How to put columns name inside the function? - pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

```
df = {
'A': [apple, hello, carrot],
'B': [4, 5, 6],
'C': [7, 8, 9]}

def columns(i):
print (df.select("A")
```

How can I put column name without mention exact column ?
Ex: I don't want "A". I want "df[i]" instead but it is not working.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please post your input and expected output datasets. This will help in understanding your use case in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print the column name:

```
def columns(i):
     print(df.columns[i])
```

if you want to print the column data:

```
def columns(i):
     print(df[df.columns[i]])
```